# cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^[]'

Tags: visual-studio-2005, c++-cli

I'm pretty new to C++/CLI and I am trying to convert a System::String to a System::Char array.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private: System::Void modeToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             Mode frmMode;
             if(frmMode.ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK){
                 array <Char>^ load [] = gcnew array<Char>(txtbxName->Text->ToCharArray());
             }
         }
```

txtbxName is a textbox inside a the form. Supposedly, this should work, but I get the compiler error:

```
error C2440: cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'cli::array<Type> ^[]'
```

for the fourth line of the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToCharArray is already giving you the array, you don't need to create a new one. In addition, as the other answerer noted, you don't need to specify `[]` to create the array variable, `array<>` is sufficient.

```
array<Char>^ load = txtbxName->Text->ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign a reference to an array (`array<Char> ^`) to a C-style array of  references to arrays (`array<Char> ^ []`).

You most likely intended this line instead:

```
array <Char>^ load = gcnew array<Char>(txtbxName->Text->ToCharArray());
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. Now I'm getting:
cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'int'
        with
        [
            Type=wchar_t
        ]
        There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Comment: The only thing you can specify as a constructor parameter to an array is the array length, not another array.